# Expand/Collapse groups RecyclerView header

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a RecyclerView adapter with two types of items. First one is Header, second one is child item. And when user tap on Header item it will expand child items. Next tap will collapse current section of items. But when I tap on Header in my `RecyclerView` it shows expanded items after second header. I don't know how to fix it

```
    class SectionedAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    private var items = mutableListOf<ListItem>()

    fun setItems(items: MutableList<ListItem>) {
        this.items = items
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    class HeaderItemViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
         fun bind(item: HeaderItem) = with(itemView) {
            textViewHeader.text = item.title
        }
    }
    class TextItemViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
         fun bind(item: TextItem) = with(itemView) {
            textViewTitle.text = item.title
            textViewContent.text = item.content
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when(viewType) {
            TYPE_HEADER -> {
                val headerView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_header, parent, false)
                return HeaderItemViewHolder(headerView)
            }
            TYPE_TEXT -> {
                val textView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_text, parent, false)
                return TextItemViewHolder(textView)
            }
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = items[position]
        when(holder) {
            is HeaderItemViewHolder -> {
                holder.bind(item as HeaderItem)
                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                    if(item.expanded) {
                        items.addAll(item.items)
                        notifyItemRangeInserted(position, item.items.size)
                    }
                    else {
                        items.removeAll(item.items)
                        notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, item.items.size)
                    }
                    item.expanded = !item.expanded

                }
            }
            is TextItemViewHolder -> {
                holder.bind(item as TextItem)
            }
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.count()
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val item = items[position]
        return when(item) {
            is HeaderItem -> TYPE_HEADER
            is TextItem -> TYPE_TEXT
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val TYPE_HEADER = 0
        const val TYPE_TEXT = 1
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve would be easier to do with nested Recyclerviews.
In your `item_header.xml` add a recyclerview, in `onBindViewHolder`, initialize this subRecyclerView for every sublist, initialize its adapter etc, populate this sub recyclerview with your required items, and let your onclick listener expand / collapse this sub recyclerView by setting its visibility to View.GONE (parent views layout height needs to be set to wrap_content for this to work)

Comment: RecyclerView will call setAdapter each time when onBindViewHolder calls, It's the worst solution. It can cause a memory leaks

Comment: if we have a huge amount of items, it can overflow UI thread and you get skipped frames and chashes. That's why I decided stop using this solution